# How to reverse WordPress comments pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how to flip the pagination of comments.

i.) Currently, I've got Admin settings set to display; Break comments into pages with  **5** top level comments per page and the **first** page displayed by default Comments should be displayed with the **newer** comments at the top of each page

However, that above in pagination displays comment of each page newest -> oldest. For example page one will have comments 06/30/2010 -> 06/29/2010 ... page 20 will show 11/7/2017 -> 08/7/2017

My question is how do I flip the pagination, so that page 20 is page 1 and page 1 is page 20 since page 1 is older much older then page 20?

I've tried the following, but that only flips the comments on each single page;

```
function wpb_reverse_comments($comments) {

    return array_reverse($comments);

}   

add_filter ('comments_array', 'wpb_reverse_comments');
```

Comment: I have never done this before but my fix will be to go to the query builder or something and change the order from desc to asc.

Comment: So what you want to do is to show recent comments first, across all comments? If the `settings` -> `discussion` option doesn't work, you might have plugins installed that overwrite the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sad old issue, the "Settings > Discussion" option to show "older" comments refers to the comments order in each page, not the general order of the comments.

From settings, the only way to do that is to set the default comments page as the last one. But like this you often have less comments than the "comments per page" settings, as you're seeing the last page.

the only working way I managed to solve this is using the comments_template_query_args filter

```
add_filter('comments_template_query_args', function($comment_args) {
    $comment_args['order'] = 'DESC';
    return $comment_args;
});
```

as shown in this [comment on wordpress track](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29462#comment:27)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you don't need to touch the code for reversing the order of comments, simply visit the WordPress menu option: "*Settings > Discusion*", and modify the attribute:

Comments should be displayed with the "**Older**" comments at the top of each page.

Tick the checkbox: Break comments into pages with "20" top level comments per page and the "**first**" page displayed by default.

and that's all.

Comment: that would work but it only does it on each page, rather then doing on all pages. So if my page 1 of comments has first comment on that page 9/10/2017 date comment and I'm displaying 5 of them per page, and the 5th comment has a date of 9/5/2017 for example... if I flip the discussion options, it will just rearrange that one page, moving 9/10/2017 to 5th position and 9/5/2017 to first position rather then moving it to page 20 (being last page) and bringing 2018 comments on page 20, and showing them on page 1. Make better sense? so I'm trying to get page 20 comments on page 1

Comment: Yes, but you should combine this attribute with the previous one. Tick the checkbox: Break comments into pages with  
"20" top level comments per page and the "first" page displayed by default.